# how to make a list out of oracle query output

Tags: python, list, cx-oracle, strip

i am trying to make a list out of the oracle query output. The list would further be used to plot the graph.
I am unable to make a clean list out of the query output. Please suggest.

```
"""
Created on Sat Sep 21 11:36:10 2019

@author: Pitanshu
"""
# import modules
import cx_Oracle

# database connection
user=input('Enter the user for database : ')
passwd=input('enter the password for the above user : ')
conn_str=user+'/'+passwd+'@localhost/orcl'
conn=cx_Oracle.connect(conn_str)

# creation of cursor
cursor=conn.cursor()
cur=cursor.execute('select distinct emp_name from employee')

employee=[]

col_names = [row[0] for row in cursor.description]
print(col_names)

for i in cur:
    employee.append(i)

print(employee)    

#closing cursor and connection
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

output received:

```
Enter the user for database : system
enter the password for the above user : ********
['EMP_NAME']
[('e',), ('d',), ('a',), ('b',), ('c',)]
```

output expected:

```
Enter the user for database : system
enter the password for the above user : ********
['EMP_NAME']
['e','d','a','b','c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the equivalent lines to:

```
for i in cur:
    employee.append(i[0]) #for python newbies, getting the only element in the list could also be done with: i[-1] or next(iter(i)) or operator.itemgetter(0)(i) or operator.itemgetter(-1)(i) or i.pop() or i.pop(0) or i.pop(-1)
```

The logic behind it is: 
When querying a relational database table, you're getting rows (in the form of lists in this case) in return. So even if you want just one column per row, you'll get a list per row with one element in it rather than the element itself.

As a naming convention, you might want to go with `employees` rather than `employee` when naming a list.

Comment: Even simpler: ``employee = [i for i, in cur]``